# Google Map does not appear in IE7/8 (but works in IE9)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geoxml3

I am using Google Maps API 3 to show a google map of Canada and a bunch of markers, but in IE7/8, it doesn't show up at all and just gives me a grey rectangle. It loads fine in Firefox/Chrome/Opera/IE9.

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var browserSupportFlag = new Boolean();
    var map;
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 3,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        navigationControl: true,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        scaleControl: true,
        streetViewControl: true,
        navigationControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.ZOOM_PAN
        },
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
        }
    };
    //var bounds = new GLatLngBounds(); 
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dealer-map"), myOptions);

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        browserSupportFlag = true;
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            currentLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, 
                                                     position.coords.longitude);
            contentString = "Location found using W3C standard";
            map.setCenter(currentLocation);
        }, function() {
        });
    }
    var geoXml = new geoXML3.parser({ map: map });
    geoXml.parse('<?php echo "/dealers.php"; ?>');

});
```

And importing using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.1&sensor=false&region=CA"></script>
```

The HTML/CSS is:

```
<div class="main-content">
<div class="wide-content">
<h3>Find a Dealer</h3>
<div style="width: 800px; height: 330px;" id="dealer-map"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Include the full html, with your CSS.  Google maps will appear to fail if you don't give your div a width/height.  You can still see the HTTP requests to v1.maps.google.com in this case.

Comment: Are you running in IE8/7 or IE9 compatibility mode.  My GMaps API3 map doesn't work in IE8/7 compatibility mode either.  Actually very few things work in those modes in IE9 currently.

Comment: I'm using IE7. No compatibility modes or anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple actually, you need to do a setCenter in all cases or else a gray box is displayed.

```
if( navigator.geolocation ) {
  ...
} else {
  map.setCenter( new google.maps.LatLng(34,-83) );
}
```

Try that and see if it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be the empty function in your navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition function.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        currentLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, 
                                                 position.coords.longitude);
        contentString = "Location found using W3C standard";
        map.setCenter(currentLocation);
        /*infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
        infowindow.setPosition(currentLocation); 
        infowindow.open(map);*/
    }, function() {  // <<< empty function may fubar ie
    });
```

Try it without the empty function, like below. Just a stab in the dark without actually having a link to follow and see the issue first hand.

```
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    currentLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, 
                                                 position.coords.longitude);
        contentString = "Location found using W3C standard";
        map.setCenter(currentLocation);

 });
```

Comment: yeah i saw that after i posted it here. but didnt fix anything. thanks though!

Comment: try commenting out all the extra code (getCurrentPosition function and that geoXML stuff) except the map instantiation code. if the map loads up with just the basic call, then you know it's in one of those functions.

Comment: running it with JUST "var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dealer-map"));" still produces nothing.

Comment: 3rd times the charm guy... check your javascript source include for the google maps.

try this:
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>

i had a similar issue and i think it's the version you're adding in. i believe that param got deprecated in version 3